# Unity how to get button input inside C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game that includes the combo system (it's a script). I currently have it so that the inputs are keys, but I want to change it so it takes button pressing input instead.

Here is the input code:

```
void Update() {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            input = new ComboInput(AttackType.heavy);
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            input = new ComboInput(AttackType.light);
}
```

The thing about UI buttons is that they take an onPressed() command, but I cant make a function to give this input because its already in an update function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a delegate for the button to call it when it has clicked.

Example:

```
private void Awake()
{
    Button buttonComponent = GetComponent<Button>();
    buttonComponent.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked)
}

private void OnButtonClicked()
{
    Debug.Log("The button has clicked!");
}
```

You have to attach this script to your Button gameobject.

Also you can add the event function directly to your button directly via inspector, but the function should be `public` in order to be accessed by inspector. If you don't want your function to be seen by other classes, then the above would be your best choice.

---

In your case, Here's my suggestion:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private Button buttonE, buttonR;

private ComboInput input;

private void Awake()
{
    buttonE.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked_E);
    buttonR.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked_R);
}

private void OnButtonClicked_E()
{
    input = new ComboInput(AttackType.heavy);
}

private void OnButtonClicked_R()
{
    input = new ComboInput(AttackType.light);
}
```

EDIT: If what you want is editing your existing combat script (not creating a new individual component), then you have to give your buttons to your combat script. That is `buttonE, buttonR`, which you have to give a reference via unity inspector. If it has done, then you're free to remove your `Update()` function, if there are no other things related to it.

Comment: alright, makes sense. But how would I implement this in a combat script?

Comment: oh, you seemed to have misunderstood me. I currently have it so you have to click keys E and R to do the input, but I want to get rid of that and make it so I can click the buttons instead. I'll go edit the question.

Comment: yeah a combat script